# Habilitar CORS em aplicação GO em App engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Minha API não responde a requisições de sites de terceiros e para isso preciso habilitar o CORS, tentei adicionar o `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"` no `app.yaml` porém recebo o seguinte erro.

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: 
>       [/Users/rafa/go/src/github.com/quickcep/api/app.yaml]
>       Unexpected attribute "http_headers" for mapping type script.
>         in "/path/api/app.yaml", line 7, column 37

O conteudo do arquivo `app.yaml` é:

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1.9
handlers:
- url: /.*
    script: _go_app
    http_headers:
        Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Há um problema na identaçao do arquivo yaml, deveria estar assim:

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1.9
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
  http_headers: 
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
```